# Merge [android-ux] into [android]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, merge

We have two tags about Android: [android](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android) (855 questions) and [android-ux](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android-ux) (58 questions). I can't see any difference in the questions using these tags, so I propose that they be merged, keeping [android](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android) as the master tag, so that it's consistent with other platform tags which don't have a -ux suffix.